# Add PdfPCell to Paragraph

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a TextField (acrofield) in the middle of a Paragraph sentence using iTextSharp. An example would be "The Effective Date is [Day] day of [Month], [Year] that this will begin."

Things I have tried:

```
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph();
para1.Add(New Phrase("The Effective Date is",fontBold));
    //The next line is where it breaks, "Insertion of illegal Element: 30"
para1.Add(CreateTextField("Day",1,0)); //this function returns a PdfPCell.
```

---

```
PdfPCell tempCell = new PdfPCell();
tempCell.AddElement(new Phrase("The Effective Date is",fontBold));
    //the next line breaks as well, "Element not allowed."
tempCell.AddElement(CreateTextField("Day",1,0));
```

---

```
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph();
para1.Add(New Phrase("The Effective Date is",fontBold));
para1.AddSpecial(CreateTextField("Day",1,0));
    //This doesn't generate an error, but the TextField is not displayed on PDF
```

---

```
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph();
PdfPTable tempTable = new PdfPTable(1);
para1.Add(New Phrase("Hello",fontBold));
tempTable.AddCell(CreateTextField("Day",1,0));
para1.Add(tempTable);
para1.Add(New Phrase("World",fontBold));
    //This doesn't generate an error, but the TextField is not displayed on PDF
```

I know the CreateTextField(...) works because I am using it in several other places on the page.

How can I add a TextField inline with other text without using tables and tediously trying to manipulate cell size to accommodate what I need?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What a strange question. A `PdfPCell` is part of a `PdfPRow`, which is in turn part of a `PdfPTable`. I can't think of any valid reason why someone would want to add a `PdfPCell` to a `Paragraph`. What you want to achieve can easily be done, but not with a `PdfPCell`. Your question sounds like "I am eating soup with a fork and that doesn't work." The answer to that question is: "Don't use a fork (and don't blame the fork), use a spoon."

Comment: Depends on how you like your soup. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is wrong. You don't want to add a `PdfPCell` to a `Paragraph`. You want to create inline form fields. That's a totally different question.

Take a look at the [GenericFields](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/GenericFields) example. In this example, we create the `Paragraph` you need like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add("The Effective Date is ");
Chunk day = new Chunk("     ");
day.setGenericTag("day");
p.add(day);
p.add(" day of ");
Chunk month = new Chunk("     ");
month.setGenericTag("month");
p.add(month);
p.add(", ");
Chunk year = new Chunk("            ");
year.setGenericTag("year");
p.add(year);
p.add(" that this will begin.");
```

Do you see how we add empty `Chunk`s where you want to add a `PdfPCell`? We use the `setGenericTag()` method on these `Chunk` object to add a form field where ever the `Chunk`s are rendered.

For this to work, we need to declare a page event:

```
writer.setPageEvent(new FieldChunk());
```

The `FieldChunk` class looks like this:

```
public class FieldChunk extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    @Override
    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
        TextField field = new TextField(writer, rect, text);
        try {
            writer.addAnnotation(field.getTextField());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ex);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time a "generic chunk" is rendered, the `onGenericTag()` method will be called passing the parameter we used in the `setGenericTag()` method as the `text` parameter. We use the `writer`, `rect` and `text` parameters to create and add a `TextField`. The result looks like this:

[image]

Feel free to adapt `rect` if you want to create a bigger text field.

**Important:** my example is written in Java. If you want to port the example to C#, just change the first letter of each method to upper case (e.g. change `add()` into `Add()`). If that doesn't work, try setting the parameter as a member variable (e.g. change `writer.setPageEvent(event)` into `writer.PageEvent = event`).

**Update:** If you want to make the field bigger, you should create a new `Rectangle`. For instance:

```
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom - 5, rect.Right, rect.Top + 2);
TextField field = new TextField(writer, rect2, text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I had no idea this was how it was supposed to be done. Converted to c# mostly painlessly.  The setPageEvent is no longer an option for itextSharp. Had to use writer.PageEvent = new FieldChunk();

Comment: What is a good way to make the fields bigger, or at least taller so it matches the rest of the font size closer? I tried manually setting the font on the chunk to the same as the rest of the line, also tried setting rect inside the OnGenericTag(), but then it drops to the bottom left edge or I have to figure out exactly what my llx and lly are for each place I need to use this. Is that the only way? Thanks again!

Comment: Beautiful! so simple I'm ashamed for asking.